# Sequel Migration not running up?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Having some trouble with the Migrations in Sequel and could use another set of eyes.
I am running a migration that looks ok but no table is created. It is definitely connecting because I can see the schema_info table has been created. -M 0/1 changes the version as you would expect but still no table.

The command:

```
sequel -m . -M 1 ~/Desktop/dbtest/testdb.yml
```

001_testdb.rb:

```
class TestDb < Sequel::Migration
  def up
    create_table( "terminals") do
      primary_key :id
      Integer :location_id
      Integer :merchant_id
      BigDecimal :terminal_id, :size=>[11, 0]
      String :reference, :size=>255
      DateTime :created_at
      DateTime :updated_at
      String :image, :default=>"default.jpg", :size=>255
  end
end
  def down
    drop_table :terminals
  end
end
```

The output in Postgres:

```
test_db=# \dt
        List of relations
Schema |    Name     | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------+-------+----------
public | schema_info | table | postgres
(1 row)

test_db=# select * from schema_info;
version 
---------
   1
(1 row)
```

Comment: seems like you should use downcased identifiers?

Comment: The def up you see there is created using Sequels own table dump. So the syntax should be ok. It also agrees with the only two tutorials that seem to exist on the subject... Thanks but I don't think that's it. I think it might be something with the naming but I don't know what. Can't find any docs on this either. Grrr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
sequel -m . -E > ~/Desktop/dbtest/testdb.yml
```

The -E adds a logger so you can see what is actually happening, and the > redirects the output into the testdb.yml logfile.  If this is your first migration, you'll probably want to drop the database and recreate it (or at least the schema_info table).  And obviously you have to be in the directory with the migrations for the -m . to work.

I would also recommend the following syntax for migration classes:

```
Class.new(Sequel::Migration) do
  def up
    create_table(:terminals) do
      primary_key :id
      Integer :location_id
      Integer :merchant_id
      BigDecimal :terminal_id, :size=>[11, 0]
      String :reference, :size=>255
      DateTime :created_at
      DateTime :updated_at
      String :image, :default=>"default.jpg", :size=>255
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :terminals
  end
end
```

Using anonymous classes instead of named classes reduces the risk of a namespace collision.

Comment: Note that these days the better anonymous migrations are done via `Sequel.migration do … end`. For more, see [the migrations document](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html).